# Array index as reference to instance

Tags: c++, arrays, reference, indexing

I have to do some code for the university which gives me a headache. Some of you brilliant minds might help me out :D

I'm asked to create a table in which studentdata is stored (like age and name), and everyone has a unique number for identifying. Though the number shall be stored in an array which will be searched by an algorhithm later on to find specific students.

Now my problem: How do I link the number in the array with the proper instance of class student? Given hint points towards the array index as reference, but I have no clue at all how to implement that.

Comment: If you need to *associate* something with something, associative containers are the way to go: `std::map<UniqueNumber, StudentData> table;`  But it probably isn't what the professor wanted.

Comment: Us brilliant minds are too brilliant to do homework.

Comment: Are you allowed to use std::map?

Answer (score 1):

Normally it would be `std::map<UniqueNumber, StudentData> table;`, but based on the "hint" the assignment probably wants two arrays of equal size:

```
UniqueNumber index[SIZE];
StudentData table[SIZE];
```

Where for each `i`, the StudentData stored in `table[i]` corresponds to the UniqueNumber stored at the same index, in `index[i]`. It's a common C programming idiom called [Parallel Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array)

Comment: If the unique number starts from 0 and has no holes, you can use that just as the array index.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You want a **map**ing from the `int ID` to the `Student*` pointer that points to the correct instance. This should help you along (atleast I hope so).